# Best way to validate files in ASP .NET Core Controller?

Tags: c#, .net, file, asp.net-core

I have an Angular application with .NET Core backend.

To perform a bulk import users can upload a file with multiple lines. Each line contains an email adress which then gets invited to create an account for the application.

For that I have an input-Field of type file.

```
<input type="file">
```

The file gets sent to my backend controller as `multipart/form-data`.

Now what is the best way to validate the file?

Currently, I'm checking the ContentType against a list of allowed ContentTypes. Furthermore, I check the size of the file because a text file with the estimated content should not use more than 250 KB.

```
var allowedFileTypes = new List<string>
  {
    ".txt",
    ".csv",
    "text/comma-separated-values",
    "text/plain",
    "text/richtext",
    "text/rtf",
    "application/vnd.ms-excel"
  };

  var maxFileSize = 250000; //250KB

  var file = Request.Form.Files.First();

  if (!allowedFileTypes.Contains(file.ContentType))
    return BadRequest();

  if (file.Length > maxFileSize)
    return BadRequest();
```

Are there any other ways how I can validate the file? Are there any security concerns I have to think of? Is it for example possible to inject malicious code inside of an .csv file.

Comment: What does "validate" and "safe to process" mean in your context? Those questions depend heavily on what you're planning on doing with the files.

Comment: Side Note: 250000 != 250KB. 250KB=250*1024=256000

Comment: @Magnetron correction: 250KB == 250000B. but: 250[KiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#kibi) == 256000B.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann depends on your context. Windows uses KB as 1024B, Linux calls it KiB. From OP context, they are probably wanting 256000B.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any other ways how I can validate the file?

Normally, we validate the file with the extnsion:

```
private string[] permittedExtensions = { ".txt", ".pdf" };

var ext = Path.GetExtension(uploadedFileName).ToLowerInvariant();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ext) || !permittedExtensions.Contains(ext))
{
    // The extension is invalid ... discontinue processing the file
}
```

> Are there any security concerns I have to think of? Is it for example possible to inject malicious code inside of an .csv file.

You can use a third party virus/malware scanning API on uploaded content.

For more details, refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#validation).